# Rails/multi_db - sending delayed_job reads to dedicated slave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using rails 2.3.11, the [multi_db](https://github.com/schoefmax/multi_db) gem to handle replication and [delayed_jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

I want that all the Reads coming from the delayed_jobs will use a dedicated slave and that the other Reads (coming from the application) will go to the rest of the slaves.

is it possible to do it with multi_db "out of the box"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a simple solution:
Since the delayed_jobs are running on a different server from application, I would just have a different database.yml file on each server, each with his own slaves.